# Where to get a signature for smart contract interaction via block explorer?

Tags: blockchain, solidity, smartcontracts, binance-smart-chain

In BSC (Binance Smart Chain) contracts I often meet a `signature` parameter but I have no idea where to get it.
If you think that it is a signature message which you need to sign with Metamask - it's not. It's just a one of parameters of the function I need to run.

Example can be found there, just look at the `purchase` function and you'll see `signature` as a last parameter - https://bscscan.com/address/0xabc306ae80595f6c7748b81d6c2efc48b32a9e22#writeContract

Answer (score 0):

**Signature is a result of signing a message with a private key.**

Example from the web3 [docs page](https://web3js.readthedocs.io/en/v1.5.2/web3-eth.html#sign):

- message `Hello world`
- signed with the private key of address `0x11f4d0A3c12e86B4b5F39B213F7E19D048276DAe`
- results in signature `0x30755ed65396facf86c53e6217c52b4daebe72aa4941d89635409de4c9c7f9466d4e9aaec7977f05e923889b33c0d0dd27d7226b6e6f56ce737465c5cfd04be400`

A contract can then verify if the signature and message (or hash of the message) can be recovered back to the signer address (cannot get the private key).

For example the OpenZeppelin [ECDSA](https://github.com/OpenZeppelin/openzeppelin-contracts/blob/master/contracts/utils/cryptography/ECDSA.sol#L88-L106) library is a developer-friendly wrapper for the low-level (EVM assembly) recovery method.

Unfortunately the contract linked in the question is passing the signature to another unspecified contract for the recovery, so I was unable to find the specific message that they're validating against and the actual recovery snippet that they're using. However, you can find more info about the signing process and on-chain recovery in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/67874993/1693192) (the mentioned `v`, `r` and `s` params are literally parts of the whole signature).